# Refresh label caption before loading?

Tags: delphi

I have a piece of code:

```
setEnableControls(false);
lblLoading.Caption:='Loading tree contents, please wait.';
someBigLoading(); 
setEnableControls(true);
lblLoading.Caption:='';
```

The problem is, the label's caption text doesn't refresh until after the "big loading" is complete. 
Is there a way to make the program process the message in the message queue, BEFORE going onto the next command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call `lblLoading.Update`. This will update the label and will not introduce any problems that can spur from processing messages in the middle of the code.

Comment: Both work fine, but can you explain why processmessages() is problematic? Also, does the property TForm.doublebuffered play any role in this?

Comment: @Goran_Mandic avoid Application.ProcessMessages(); whenever possible because [it usually causes reentrancy issues](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm)